# How do I implement a custom shell script to kill local ports?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I am currently having a shell script to start a back-end server. I want to include a custom shell script such that on terminating the script should kill a specific port (example: 9999) in LOCAL only and restarting the script should start all fresh.

I have tried alias kill3000="lsof -i:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9" adding to the script. However, these doesn't terminate the port. Adding a copy of the current shell script, I have with me.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export ENV_NAME=local

PROFILE=$1
BUILD_OR_RUN=$2

if [  ! -z "$1" ]; then
    PROFILE=$1
else    
    PROFILE='default'
fi

echo "Using Profile = $PROFILE"

if [  ! -z "$2"  ]; then
    if [ $BUILD_OR_RUN = 'b' ]; then
        echo "Running clean install"
        mvn clean install -Pjs-debug,no-docker -DskipTests=true
    fi 
fi


SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE="$PROFILE" java -jar target/****-*.jar --HOSTNAME=local
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
alias kill3000="lsof -i:3000 | grep LISTEN | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs -r kill -9"
```